# Text wrapping inside StackPanel (WP7)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I'd like to wrap text contained in three `TextBlock`s inside a `StackPanel` without writing `TextWrapping="Wrap"` for each `TextBlock` (sometimes there may be more of those):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Distance, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So if I dynamically add another `TextBlock` it should wrap automatically (I don't want to do it inside my code-behind file)

In other words - I'd like to write style that would be automatically applied. In CSS it would be something like that:

```
listbox textblock {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This contains my ListBox:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <views:ListItem Margin="12,6,0,0" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Are you adding the textbox to the item template dynamically? E.g. not just adding an item to the list box?

Comment: At this phase of the project - no.

Comment: I'm adding `ListBoxItem`s dynamically, but there are always three `TextBlock`s inside each of them. Actually it doesn't matter - right now I just want to define a style that would be applied to each `TextBlock` in my `ListBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding a style for `TextBlock`?  I.e.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify a `Width` constraint for the `TextBlock`, it will *not* wrap its text content. As the `StackPanel` does *not* resize its contents, it will *never* pass any `Width` constraints to the `TextBlock`s inside and so they will *never* wrap. Setting the `TextWrapping` property to `Wrap` is *not* enough to make the text content wrap, so applying a `Style` with this property set will *not* do what you want.